# Sharepoint list view threshold maximum limit?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, threshold

I have a client who has already exceeded default sharepoint threshold. [image]

I understand that it is not advisable to increase the default limit but in my case I am left with no other option than to increase the threshold .

Can anyone tell me what is the **max limit** for threshold I can put? Client is expecting another 50000 files going into the document store.

As per [this](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010378155.aspx?redir=0) it says max limit is 50 million. How much can I increase it to?

Would I look like a fool if I simply increase it to 5 or or 10 million

Answer (score 5, accepted):

50 million, if that's what the article says.

It's really just a question of performance and scalability, but if the client really needs a quarter million items in a list, he'll have to accept a little waiting time.

Read [this](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010378155.aspx?redir=0#_Toc268174141), where it says that SQL Server escalates to a full table lock if you exceed 5000 items.  That means that you're probably going to be making other people wait, if they also require access to the same table at the same time.

Use the smallest possible threshold that will satisfy the client.  Warn him that there may be performance penalties.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to go above 5000 items in a view for performance reasons. Is there a way you can redesign the lists?

[this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.14%29.aspx#ListLibrary) says the max limit is 30 million items in a list. Which would be your limiting factor on the view threshold